# How to analyse the relationship between the expression and matrix eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an expression:
$$2\cdot\mathbb{R}\left ( \frac{P_{a}^{H}\left ( A^{H}A \right )P_{a}}{P^{H}\left ( A^{H}A \right )P}+\frac{\left | P_{a}^{H}\left ( A^{H}A \right )P \right |^{2}}{\left | P^{H}\left ( A^{H}A \right )P \right |^{2}} \right)$$
where $P$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix with parameters of $\alpha, P_{a}$ means $\frac{\partial P}{\partial \alpha },$ $H$ means Conjugate transpose, $A$ is a $25\times 2$  matrix.
The question is: I know the two eigenvalues of $\left ( A^{H}A \right ), \lambda _{1}$ and $\lambda _{2},$ how to analyse the relationship between $\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{2}}$ and the expression above, it can be a size relationship or other?

Comment: Somethings up with your LaTeX

Comment: In mathjax, you need to surround LaTeX with a dollar sign on each end, to render on this site.  (Please review my edit.)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Your very welcome, @MH_Dai.